# How do I get rid of the word "base: " from my error message in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling

This is how the error that I want is called in my model:

```
validate :number_of_clients

def number_of_clients
      errors[:base] << "You cannot add another client" if
        Authorization.current_user.plan.num_of_clients <= Authorization.current_user.clients.count 
end
```

Even when I changed the errors line to the following it produced the same result:

```
errors.add(:base, "You cannot add another client")
errors.add_to_base("You cannot add another client")
```

This is how the error messages are parsed (in an _error_messages partial):

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>
            prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
    <p> There were problems with the following fields:</p>
    <ul>
        <% object.errors.full_messages.each_full do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>   
    </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This is how the error message shows up in my html:

```
There were errors: base: You cannot
add another client
```

Edit 1: What I want to happen is to get rid of the text "base: " in the actual message. So I would like it to say `There were errors: You cannot add another client`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
errors.add_to_base("Your message")
```

Comment: actually, when I do that I get this: `DEPRECATION WARNING: Errors#add_to_base(msg) has been deprecated, use Errors#add(:base, msg) instead. `

Comment: Ok, i guess you use rails 3.0 then.
Can you try to display msg.to_yaml ?

Comment: How would I do that in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    validate :number_of_clients

    def number_of_clients
      errors.add(:base, "You cannot add another client") if Authorization.current_user.plan.num_of_clients <= Authorization.current_user.clients.count 
      errors.blank? #You have to return false to not proceed

    end
```

if :base appear, well why don't you try to do:

```
MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_reader :my_mistery_field

  validate :number_of_clients

  def number_of_clients
    errors.add(:my_mistery_field, "You cannot add another client") if Authorization.current_user.plan.num_of_clients <= Authorization.current_user.clients.count 
    errors.blank? #You have to return false to not proceed
  end


end
```

On your file en.yml (or lang.yml whatever your lang default app)

en.yml

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      my_class:
        my_mistery_field:   "Don't touch on my mistery field"
```

of course that is used for other things but who tell we can't tricking Rails?

Hope it helps you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding an entry `base: ""` to the appropriate spot under `activerecord.attributes` in my `en.yml` file.